# Дублирование анимации во время отрисовки libgdx

Tags: libgdx

Обнаружил проблему, во время игры, генерируются объекты и падают из-за экрана. Объекты эти могут быть разного типа. На некоторых есть анимация. Первые несколько штук которые имеют анимацию, отрисовывают ее нормально. Но через какой-то промежуток времени у одного нового объекта появляется несколько слоев с анимацией. Несколько раз проверял, что объект создается только один, поэтому вариант с тем что происходит наложение объектов я отбросил. Подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибся.

Вот метод, где я получаю текстуру к объекту

```
public void createTexture() {

    if (!(Prefers.getInstance().settings.getInteger(BoltType.DICK) == 0)) {
        sprite = new Sprite(ResourceManager.getResourceManager().getTexture("bolt"));
        sprite.setBounds(body.getPosition().x - BOLT_RADIUS * 3, body.getPosition().y - BOLT_RADIUS * 2, BOLT_RADIUS * 3, BOLT_RADIUS * 2);
        sprite.setOriginCenter();
    } else {
        anim = new Animations(ResourceManager.getResourceManager().getRegions("bolt"), true, 0.06f);
        anim.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - BOLT_RADIUS * 2, body.getPosition().y - BOLT_RADIUS * 2);
        anim.setSize(BOLT_RADIUS * 4, BOLT_RADIUS * 3);
        anim.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
        anim.setOriginCenter();
    }
}
```

Ниже - отрисовка актера

```
setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y * MobilesScreen.RATIO_PPM);

    if (sprite != null) {
        sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - BOLT_RADIUS, body.getPosition().y - BOLT_RADIUS);
        sprite.setRotation(MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * body.getAngle());
    }
    if (dick != null) {
        dick.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - BOLT_RADIUS * 2, body.getPosition().y - BOLT_RADIUS * 2);
        dick.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
    }
```

Отрисовка текстур

```
 @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        if (dick != null) {
            dick.animRender(batch);
        }
        if (sprite != null) {
            sprite.draw(batch);
        }
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: В общем то нашел в чем проблема. когда объекты улетают за экран, физические тела удаляются, а вот актеры копятся в масиве актеров. которые сейчас отрисовываются

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена. После удаления физических тел не удалял актеров.